# import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult cannot be cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, adt, google-play-services

I was working on the latest Google API for detected activity. So Inorder to try that I download the sample code from

```
http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html
```

I imported the google-play-service-lib. have set it as a library for my project. I have also checked for required permissions, but I am still getting an error. I have also set target build to Google APIs

```
 import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult cannot be cannot be resolved.
```

I was able to import other samples from google play services folder and they are running fine. Can anyone point out what error I am making ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix it,....after reinstalling and adding and removing google play services for several times.

Answer (score 0):

R u sure added the googleplayservices library if added check both are in same folder(path) are not by opening the project -> properties -> resource